# How to estimate a square root of a decimal number?

Tags: square-numbers

The way I estimate square roots, is by finding the closest lowest perfect square, then adding decimals to the number to determine the estimation. **How do I estimate the square root of a number with decimals using this method using the number $3.51$ for example?**

I know how to estimate for whole numbers using this method but I'm confused on the decimal numbers. When I used this same method on $3.51$, I tested $1.8^2$ and $1.9^2$ to see which one was closer. $1.9^2$ $(3.61)$ was closer to $3.51$ than $1.8^2$  $(3.24)$. But in my math book, the answer was that $1.8$ was the correct estimate.

**How and why?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is a method for finding square roots of any number upto certain digits ig

Comment: If you are presenting the problem accurately, and if your math book didn't explicitly say it wanted an underestimate, then the book is wrong. $\sqrt{3.51}=1.873\dotsc$, so $1.9$ is the better estimate.

Comment: Do you have anything to say about the answer and the comments that have been posted, Haseen?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the square root of $3.51$ and you know that it's somewhere between $1.8$ (square $3.24$) and $1.9$ (square $3.61$).

As the square of $1.9$ is the closest, you start from there:

$3.51 = (1.9 - \alpha)^2 = 1.9^2 - 3.8 \alpha + \alpha^2$

As $\alpha$ is quite small, let's drop it and continue the approximation:

$$3.51 \approx 3.61 - 3.8 \alpha$$
$$\alpha \approx \frac{3.61 - 3.51}{3.8}$$ ($3.8$ is close to $4$)
$$\alpha \approx \frac{0.10}{4} \approx 0.025$$
Hence: $1.9 - 0.025 = 1.875$ is a better approximation than $1.9$.

Comment: What is 'a' being represented as?

Comment: @HaseenSiddiqui: what do you mean?

Comment: Like what is 'a' representing?

Comment: And where did 3.8 come from

Comment: @HaseenSiddiqui: $3.8$ is a direct consequence of the calculation, something which should be known by any person from the third year in secondary school (age 14). How old are you?